# C/C++ language file generation with Apache Velocity

Tags: java, c++, apache, velocity, directive

I need to generate a C/C++ source file and I thought to use velocity because I already have the sample output file and only need to change some dynamic parts from the sample. The problem is that the template file contains a lot of **#define**'s and **#include**'s. Is there a way to disable the **#define** and **#include** directives from Velocity? because I won't be needing them when generating.

I also thought about escaping those parts of the file with **#[[...]]#** but this would imply many changes in the template file and I want to keep it the same as the sample file as much as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance object has a removeDirective(String name) method, so I guess you only have to call:

```
runtimeInstance.removeDirective("define");
runtimeInstance.removeDirective("include");
```

to disable both directives.